MCP - SalesforceInteractions.listener is not bringing the segment of the user
We have a code that we are using in Marketing Cloud Personalization to get the segment of the users and depending if they are in that segment the background-color or the color of the content-zone should change.
SalesforceInteractions.listener("IdentifyUser", (event) => {
        const userSegments = event.user.segments || [];
        const contentZone = document.querySelector(".HERE GOES THE CLASS");

        if (userSegments.includes("segmentName")) { 
            if (contentZone) {
                contentZone.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            }
        }
    });

So far this isnt working. Is there a way to bring the segment on the mapping to be able to do this change in the content-zone? We debugged every part of the code and not even from the point 1 is working.

The way you are using the listener is wrong. Ideally, its should be
 SalesforceInteractions.listener("{{Click/Submit/Change...}}","{{.Classname/#Id}}", (event) => {
     // Your code goes here
})

